# What does the "-" mean in front of a ruby symbol?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

When I had a look into the `ActiveRecord` source today, I stumbled upon these lines

```rb
name = -name.to_s
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2459c20afb508c987347f52148210d874a9af4fa/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L24

and

```rb
ar.aggregate_reflections = ar.aggregate_reflections.merge(-name.to_s => reflection)
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2459c20afb508c987347f52148210d874a9af4fa/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L29

What purpose does the `-` operator serve for on the symbol `name`?

Comment: BTW, `name` is a variable, not a symbol. And `-` is applied to the result of `name.to_s` which returns a string.

Comment: To be clear, that's a **`String`**, not a `Symbol`. There is such method as `Symbol#-@`: `-:foo #=> NoMethodError: undefined method '-@' for :foo:Symbol`

Comment: "Symbol" is a class in ruby. It's confusing/misleading to refer to arbitrary variables as "symbols", especially when the variable is *not* a `Symbol`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's [`String#-@`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/String.html#2D-40-method):

> Returns a frozen, possibly pre-existing copy of the string.

Example:

```
a = "foo"
b = "foo"

a.object_id #=> 6980
b.object_id #=> 7000
```

vs:

```
a = -"foo"
b = -"foo"

a.object_id #=> 6980
b.object_id #=> 6980
```

Answer (score 6):

> What purpose does the `-` operator serve for on the symbol `name`?

You have your precedence rules wrong: the binary message sending operator (`.`) has higher precedence than everything else, which means `-` is *not* applied to the expression `name` but to the expression `name.to_s`.

In other words, you seem to think that this expression is parsed like this:

```ruby
(-name).to_s
# which is the same as
name.-@().to_s()
```

but it is actually parsed as

```ruby
-(name.to_s)
# which is the same as
name.to_s().-@()
```

Now, we don't know what `name` is, but unless someone is seriously messing with you, [`#to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#to_s-method) *should* return a [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html). In other words, the operator is *not* applied to a [`Symbol`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html), as you thought.

Hence, we know that we are sending the message `-@` to a `String` and can thus look up what [`String#-@`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#2D-40-method) does in the documentation:

> ## `-string` → `frozen_string`
>
> Returns a frozen, possibly pre-existing copy of the string.
>
> The returned String will be deduplicated as long as it does not have any instance variables set on it.

Dynamically created `String`s are not frozen by default. Only static `String` literals are, depending on your setting of the magic comment `# frozen_string_literals: true`. `String#-@` was added as an alias for [`String#freeze`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#freeze-method) to allow you to freeze and de-duplicate a `String` with as little syntactic noise as possible.

The opposite operation is also available as [`String#+@`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#2B-40-method).

Comment: `freeze` returns a frozen string but it doesn't necessarily de-duplicate it.